# How to build .net core application for debian:jessie

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, debian-jessie

I have created a sample  application using .net core. I need to build the application for debian:jessie os. I have following commands

```
dotnet restore MySampleApp.sln -r -debian:jessie-x64

dotnet build MySampleApp.csproj --verbosity q -c Release -r -debian:jessie-x64
```

But it shows error message like this

```
error : NETSDK1056: Project is targeting runtime '-debian:jessie-x64' but did not resolve any runtime-specific packages. This runtime may not be supported by the target framework.
```

But I can run the same application using alpine Linux without any error

```
dotnet restore MySampleApp.sln -r alpine.3.7-x64

dotnet build MySampleApp.csproj --verbosity q -c Release -r alpine.3.7-x64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team has provided [a complete list for **Runtime IDentifiers** on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json).

Indeed, there's a `RID` of `alpine.3.7-x64` defined in [line30](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/e99ec129cfd594d53f4390bf97d1d736cff6f860/src/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json#L30). But as you can see [between the line129 and Line233](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/9da775f39d7cd3a20ae4732b96d7174ca634339a/pkg/Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/runtime.json#L129-L233), there's no such a `RID` whose name is `debian:jessie-x64`.

You need to use `debian.8-x64` instead.